# Reset/Remove Default Column Values from folders

Tags: column, pnp-powershell, default

I am searching for a better way to reset/remove default column values from specific folders using PowerShell.

I realize that it can be done through the library settings but I need to do this for about 50 folders with 4+ values per folder. So manually is not a very good option.

Has anyone dealt with this before?

I considered using the `cmdlet 
Set-PnPDefaultColumnValues` and just leaving the value blank(""). It will not allow me to use "" I could use " " but that does not work for managed metadata. There must be better way to remove default column values. I find it hard to believe that it would be a one way road where you can set it with powershell but cannot reset/remove.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `Clear-PnPDefaultColumnValues`

Comment: I did not even realize that one was available, for some weird reason it does not show up in the list when I am trying to use it in ISE, Thank you for making this aware to me. I am going to explore this option.

Comment: No worries.It should work although I have come across and issue where it does not work when the field is a managed metadata one.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I am actaully trying to use it for managed metadata so I may have to explore another option for that column

Answer (score 0):

[`Set-PnPDefaultColumnValues`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpdefaultcolumnvalues?view=sharepoint-ps) seems the best way to go. Combine it with [`Get-PnPFolder`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpfolder?view=sharepoint-ps) and you're ready to go.